# Difference between mongod and mongodb upstart jobs

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

- I just noticed that there are two possible ways to start mongodb:

  - service mongodb start (uses /etc/mongod.conf)
  - service mongod start (uses /etc/mongodb.conf)

Can someone tell me what's the difference between the two?

I'm running mongodb 2.6.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you had MongoDB 2.4 installed previously.

In MongoDB 2.4 the service was called `mongodb` and used `/etc/mongodb.conf` (ref: [Install MongoDB 2.4 on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)).

With MongoDB 2.6 there was an attempt to have more standard package names across Linux distributions, so the service was renamed to `mongod` (to reflect the actual daemon being started) and the config was changed to `mongod.conf` (ref: [Install MongoDB 2.6 on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)).

Comment: Thanks @stennie, that helps. Let me see if I can officially find documentation about this.

Comment: The reference links are to the official documentation but if you want a more specific source the packaging changes between 2.4 and 2.6 were related to [SERVER-3579](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3579).

Comment: Seems like in Ubuntu 20.04 with mongodb 3.6.9 things have changed back to `mongodb` and `/etc/mongodb.conf` again https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/database/mongodb-server